# How to hide elements when a smartform field is null

Tags: c#, html, ektron

I have an alert bar that gets its text from a smartform. I'm trying to set this up so when the smartform field "Alert" is null then the alert bar will be hidden. Here's my Code:

```html
<div runat="server" ID="alertBox"  class="alert alert-danger">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
       <center>
           <CMS:ContentBlock ID="alert" runat="server" Visible="true" DisplayXslt="/xmlfiles/Alert.xslt" DefaultContentID="2147499035" CssClass="text" />
    </center>
</div>
```

Here's my Code Behind for this so far:

```
   XmlDocument al = new XmlDocument();
    if (al.SelectSingleNode("/root/Alert") != null)
    {
        alertBox.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        alertBox.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Why not: alertBox.Visible = al.SelectSingleNode("/root/Alert") != null;

Comment: @Kevin This just made my alert box disappear as a whole. I'm looking for more of an if/then statement so if there's text in the box the alert will activate. If no text then alert will disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start out making sure your XmlDocument is referencing the smartform xml from your content block control.

```cs
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(alert.EkItem.Html);
```

With that out of the way, here's how I would test to verify that (a) the node exists and (b) the node contains text.

```cs
string alertContent;

// If dealing with a plain-text field...
var txtAlertNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/txtAlert");
alertContent = txtAlertNode?.InnerText;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(alertContent))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No txtAlert content.");
    // alertBox.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("ALERT: " + alertContent);
    // alertBox.Visible = true;
}

// If dealing with a rich-text field...
var rtfAlertNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/rtfAlert");
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rtfAlertNode?.InnerText))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No rtfAlert content.");
    // alertBox.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    alertContent = rtfAlertNode.InnerXml;
    Console.WriteLine("ALERT: " + alertContent);
    // alertBox.Visible = true;
}
```

But since you have the content block control rendering the actual alert content, you could get away with something like this.

```cs
var alertNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/Alert");
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(alertNode?.InnerText))
{
    alertBox.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    alertBox.Visible = true;
}
```

In Ektron SmartForms, there is the option of making a field optional, so it's possible that the `/root/Alert` node will be null. But it's also possible that the node will exist in the xml and simple not have any content. If it is configured as a rich-text field, then it can be difficult to completely clear out the field's HTML - often you end up with xml that looks like the following:

```xml
<root>
    <Alert>
        <p></p>
    </Alert>
</root>
```

That's why I'm testing the `InnerText` property of the node. I'm using the [Null-Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) `?.` to account for the fact that the node itself might be null. If your Ektron site is not using the newer C# language features (I know, null-conditionals have been around for a few years now.), then you'd have to check for null separately.

```cs
var alertNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/Alert");
if (alertNode != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(alertNode.InnerText))
{
    alertBox.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    alertBox.Visible = true;
}
```

---

I'd like to suggest an alternative, if I may. I see from your code that you are already using an XSLT to display the content of the alert. You could move the markup of the `alertBox` div into your XSLT and perform the "null-or-empty" test in there. Then you wouldn't need any code-behind for this particular feature.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:call-template name="alertBox">
      <xsl:with-param name="content" select="root/txtAlert/text()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:call-template name="alertBox">
      <xsl:with-param name="content" select="root/rtfAlert/node()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="alertBox">
    <xsl:param name="content"/>
    <xsl:if test="$content and (string-length(translate(normalize-space($content/text()), ' ', '')) &gt; 0 or string-length(translate(normalize-space($content), ' ', '')) &gt; 0)">
      <div runat="server" ID="alertBox"  class="alert alert-danger">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <center>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
        </center>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the `alertBox` template in this XSLT will work for both plain-text and rich-text fields. It is using `copy-of` to display whatever is passed in, so when calling the template, care needs to be taken to pass in either the `text()` (plain-text) or `node()` (html/rich-text) of the element according to its type.

Comment: Thank you So much for this I knew i was going down the right path. This helped me Tremendously